StreetPass Mii met via invitation after the Nintendo Network shutdown
So I recently got a 3DS, and have been loving it so far, even with the online services shut down. I even managed to get a street pass just two days after getting the console. But recently I checked my Mii Plaza, and it said I had found a Mii "via invitation" called David.
I didn't get a notification nor a street pass hit, and I obviously couldn't have met it online since it's shut down, so I was confused. I checked the activity log, and I only played Mario 3D Land and Pokémon Blue on that day. Assuming it isn't the latter, how could I find a Mii through SM3DL without playing online?

Sadly the only online service that only works is the game and system updates. I own a 3DS and a Wii U (both taken down) and I was actually able to update my games (Which was shocking to know when I played Mario Maker and Minecraft: Wii U edition on the same version for so long before I connected to the internet).
I do think you can still receive Miis and ghost data (depending on the game) via. StreetPass.

When I connected to the internet on my 3DS, I suddenly received 50 Miis in StreetPass Mii Plaza. So maybe it was an online thing considering the fact you didn't get a hit.
